# Are all ObjectId's in mongo even numbers?

Tags: node.js, mongodb

I am trying to divide work into workers using modulus based on mongo ObjectId, with nodejs native driver. My problem is:

```
var hash = parseInt( allHashes[i]._id , 16 );
console.log(hash % 2)
```

The result is always 0. Could this be true? Does mongo only generate even objectIds or am I doing something wrong?

Thx!

Comment: https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/method/ObjectId/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I finally figured it out. Converting ObjectId to int in JS will result in a number larger than maxint, so it's probably ending in multiple 0's.
The solution was to only convert the last 3-bytes (counter, starting with a random value). So:

```
var hash = parseInt( allHashes[i]._id.substr( 17, 6 ) , 16 );
```

And now the distribution is suitable for dividing work between workers.